# How to get MySQL database values in dropdown using python cgi?

Tags: python, mysql, html-select

I've created a webpage using Python cgi, now I want fill my HTML dropdown with database values. I don't know how get MySQL database values into dropdown.

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import MySQLdb
import cgi

import cgitb; cgitb.enable()

print "content-type:text/html\r\n\r\n"
print '<html>'
print '<head>'
print '<meta charset="utf-8">'
print '<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">'
print '<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">'
print '<link rel="stylesheet" href="/powersupply/cssmenu/styles.css">'
print '<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>'
print '<script src="/powersupply/cssmenu/script.js"></script>'
print '<title>Power Supply Testing</title>'
print '<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/newstyle.css">'
print '</head>'
print '<body>'

print '<form name="myform" method="post" action="">'
print '<div>'
print '<fieldset class="fieldset">'
print '<legend>Power Supply Testing</legend>'
print '<table>'
print '<tr>'
print '<td>'
print '<label class="label">Serial Num Option:</label>'
print '</td>'
print '<td>'
print '<select class="textbox">'
print '<option value="serialno">Serial Num Auto Generate</option>'
print '<option value="barcode">Barcode Scanner Capture</option>'
print '</select>'
print '</td>'
print '<td>'
print '<label class="label">Serial Num:</label>'
print '</td>'
print '<td>'
print '<input class="textbox" type="text" name="serial" id="serial"/>'
print '</td>'
print '<td>'
print '<label class="label">PartNum:</label>'
print '</td>'
print '<td>'
print '<select class="textbox">'
print '<option value=""></option>'
print '</select>'
print '</td>'
print '</tr>'
print '<tr>'
print '<td>'
print '<label class="label">Revision No:</label>'
print '</td>'
print '<td>'
print '<select class="textbox">'
print '<option value=""></option>'
print '</select>'
print '</td>'
print '<td>'
print '<label class="label">Description:</label>'
print '</td>'
print '<td>'
print '<input class="textbox" type="text" name="description" id="description"/>'
print '</td>'
print '</tr>'
print '</table>'
print '<table>'
print '<tr>'
print '<td>'
print '<input class="clicktosave" type="submit" value="CLICK TO RECORD"/>'
print '</td>'
print '</tr>'
print '<tr>'
print '<td>'
print '<input class="cancelbutton" type="reset" name="cancel" value="CANCEL" id="cancel"/>'
print '</td>'
print '</tr>'
print '</table>'
print '</fieldset>'
print '</div>'
print '</form>'


print '</body>'
print '</html>'
```

I want to add MySQL database values in the dropdown. in between Python code PHP script is not working. Is there any way to get database values?

Comment: You don't even seen to have tried. And what does PHP have to do with anything?

Comment: in html php script is used for filling database value to  dropdown. to do that    file extension should be .php

Comment: to populate html dropdownlist with database value, you have to use php script   `<select name="owner">
<?php 
$sql = mysql_query("SELECT username FROM users");
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql)){
echo "<option value=\"owner1\">" . $row['username'] . "</option>";
}
?>
</select>`  this kind of option is there in python...?

Comment: In Python you need to write Python code, not PHP. You have obviously made a start by importing MySQLdb. Now read the documentation for that module and write the relevant code.

Comment: let's forget about php, please tell me how to populate dropdown with database values in python...?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are going to want to use something like [this](http://mysql-python.sourceforge.net/MySQLdb.html).

Here is an example of how to use this package:

```
import MySQLdb

def db_dropdown():  # Execute query
    db = MySQLdb.connect(user='root', db='test', passwd='test', host='ip-address')  # Your DB details here
    cursor = db.cursor()

    sql = 'SELECT SUM(regressnum) FROM testlog WHERE buildnumber = %s AND productid = 41))' \
          % build_number  # Parse in a variable into the query
    cursor.execute(sql)
    list_tested = cursor.fetchall()  # Get query response and store in variable
    list_tested = [i for sub in list_tested for i in sub]  # Convert to list from tuple

    return list_tested

def print_dropdown(data):  # Print the dropdown
    print '<div>'
    print '<select>'
    for i in data:
        print '<option value="%s"selected>%s</option>' % (i, i)
    print '</select>'
    print '</div>'
```

Example usage:

```
print_dropdown(db_dropdown())
```

Obviously this can be expanded upon and can be made to query anytihng and produce anything.

Comment: and please tell me how to store selected dropdown value to variable...?